# Irreducible representations of $SO(3)$

Tags: representation-theory

The irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ are in bijection with those of $SU(2)$ such that $-E_2$ acts trivially. Now we know that the space $V_n$ of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ is the span of the monomials $p_k=z_1^kz_2^{n-k}$ with the integer parameter $k$ ranging over $0\le k\le n$ are the irr. representations of $SU(2)$.

Now how can we conclude that the irr. representations of $SO(3)$ are these with the $n$ even..?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: But why? How can I show that?

Comment: You've answered yourself: the $V_n$'s on which $-\operatorname{Id}_2$ acts trivially are those with even $n$.